# how to handle "Invalid closing quote at line 2; found "\"" instead of delimiter ","" in newman

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I am running postman collection in command prompt

> newman run "path\FCE_CalculateRate.postman_collection.json" -e "path\DevEnv.postman_environment.json" -d "path\Automated_Testing_Input_Data_06Apr18.csv"

Prompts error message : Invalid closing quote at line 2; found "\"" instead of delimiter ","

Same data sheet running with POSTMAN tool without any issues.

The CSV file contains data within double " ex: "NUE".  Attached the screen short of data file

Any idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Newman is not parsing the double-quotes correctly.  I ran into this too and had better luck writing my strings in the CSV using the syntax below:

"\"STRING_TEXT_HERE\""   instead of "STRING_TEXT_HERE"

hopefully this helps you.